# Error in a simple PHP submit form

Tags: php, forms, contact-form

I hope someone can help me out with this problem I'm facing.

I have a simple PHP form which is showing an error I don't know why, here's the code:

```
        <?php

// Get values from form
$name=$_POST['name'];
$email=$_POST['email'];
$emailconfirmation=$_POST['emailconfirmation'];
$phone=$_POST['phone'];
$address=$_POST['address'];
$postcode=$_POST['postcode'];
$eventarea=$_POST['eventarea'];
$typeevent=$_POST['typeevent'];
$eventdate=$_POST['eventdate'];
$guestnumber=$_POST['guestnumber'];
$extraguests=$_POST['extraguests'];
$siteformarquee=$_POST['siteformarquee'];
$seatedorstanding=$_POST['seatedorstanding'];
$dancefloor=$_POST['dancefloor'];
$servicetent=$_POST['servicetent'];
$surfacemarquee=$_POST['surfacemarquee'];
$details=$_POST['details'];
$town=$_POST['town'];




$to = "email@email.com, email2@email.com";
$subject = "Quote to review from Elite Marquees";
$message = " Name: " . $name . "\r\n Town of the Event: " . $town . "\r\n Telephone Number: " . $phone . "\r\n Email: " . $email . "\r\n Confirm Email Address: " . $emailconfirmation . "\r\n Address: " . $address . "\r\n Post Code: " . $postcode . "\r\n The area where your event will take place: " . $eventarea . "\r\n Type of the Event: " . $typeevent . "\r\n Date of the Event: " . $eventdate . "\r\n Number of Guests: " . $guestnumber . "\r\n If a wedding how many extra guests for the evening?: " . $extraguests . "\r\n Town Where the Event will take place: " . $town . "\r\n Do you have a venue or site for the marquee?: " . $siteformarquee . "\r\n Will your guests be seated or standing?: " . $seatedorstanding . "\r\n Do you require a dance floor?: " . $dancefloor . "\r\n Do you require a service tent?: " . $servicetent . "\r\n Type of surface the marquee will be erected on?: " . $surfacemarquee . "\r\n Details or Questions?: " . $details;


/*$from = "Elite Marquees";*/
$headers = "From: Elite Marquees <info@elitemarquees.com>" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n"; 

if(@mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers))
{
  print "<script>document.location.href='http://elite-marquees.co.uk/success.html';</script>";

}else{
  echo "Error! Please try again.";
}



?>
```

[Live Form](http://elite-marquees.co.uk/get-a-quote.php)

Can someone please help me out?

Thanks!

Comment: Remove `@` before of your `mail()` and retest.

Comment: @Tularis, the "Error! Please try again." is displayed.

Comment: @Tularis, The exact error is not known since the OP is silencing it with the `@` operator.

Comment: @Tularis The error is "Error! Please Try again".

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran Thanks, for your reply. I removed the @ in `if(mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers))` but without success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the email you're using as FROM must be on the same server as the website, meaning info@elite-marquees.co.uk would work just fine but not info@elitemarquees.com

try adding a fifth parameter to your mail() command:

`mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers,"-f info@elitemarquees.com");`

Comment: Awesome! It was a silly mistake from me I wanted to use `info@elite-marquees.co.uk` instead of the dotcom. Thanks again Fabio!

Answer (score 0):

[Php's Mail Function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) Return Values:

> Returns TRUE if the mail was successfully accepted for delivery,
> FALSE otherwise.
>
> It is important to note that just because the mail was accepted for
> delivery, it does NOT mean the mail will actually reach the intended
> destination.

Essentially, you mail function is failing.

First, check if you can send a test mail on the server. If you can't the server settings are not configured to use email.

Try and call a really simple, hard-coded `mail()`.

If it is still failing, then it's 99% your server set up. Check your `php.ini` settings, and make sure your server can support sending out emails.

Comment: I removed `<info@elitemarquees.com>` and it worked. But now the email I got is sent from "Unknown Sender" and go directly to the spam folder. Any suggestions on how I can Show the Sender's name to avoid the spam folder? Thanks a lot!

Comment: note that the email you're using as FROM must be on the same server

Answer (score 0):

Which error are you getting?
And is your php.ini updated for the following lines?

```
[mail function]
; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/smtp
SMTP = localhost
; http://php.net/smtp-port
smtp_port = 25

; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/sendmail-from
sendmail_from = Your Email ID

; For Unix only.  You may supply arguments as well (default: "sendmail -t -i").
; http://php.net/sendmail-path
sendmail_path =/usr/sbin/sendmail
```

Comment: The error I'm getting is "Error! Please Try again". Thank you for your response Sanket. I think it's coming from the php.ini file.

Comment: I can't update the php.ini file because I don't have a Cpanel access. I removed `<info@elitemarquees.com>` and it's working now. But the email received is coming from "Unknown Sender" and go directly to the Spam folder. Any suggestions in order to show the sender without updating the php.ini file? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly remove the @ before the mail function . After try again if error occur again and again  you must check whats the value are comes for you can use for that var_dump(mail(your mail)) or die; function to check the value if it give the null that means something is missing. Then again check var_dump for other values you will soon find the error 
May be that help you .

Answer (score 0):

The problem was from `<info@elitemarquees.com>` I changed it to `<info@elitemarquees.co.uk>` and now it's working.

**Thanks to all of you guys! You rock!**